# Sorting a set java

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, comparator

I am trying to sort a set of objects, using the below code,

```
CompletableFuture<Set<AnnouncementDTO>> announcementsDTO = announcementRepository.findByZoneId(id)
            .thenApply(o ->
                o.stream()
                    .sorted(new Comparator<Announcement>() {
                        public int compare(Announcement left, Announcement right) {
                            log.debug("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
                            log.debug("Left Date" + left.getCreatedDate().toLocalDateTime());
                            log.debug("Right Date" + right.getCreatedDate().toLocalDateTime());
                            log.debug("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
                            if (right.getCreatedDate().toLocalDateTime().isBefore(left.getCreatedDate().toLocalDateTime())) {
                                return -1;
                            } else {
                                return 1;
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .map(announcementMapper::mapToDto)
                    .map(it -> {
                        it.setVersion(null);
                        return it;
                    })
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Which is not working any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You never return `0` - your comparator fails the contract. Also `.sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> .getCreatedDate().toLocalDateTime()))` would be idiomatic. I would **strongly** suggest against logging in a `Comparator` unless you are sorting a tiny data set. In fact I like nothing about your logging - it's heavy and pointless: it doesn't use parameterisation so will have a massive impact on production, it logs 4 times when it could log once, it logs 4 lines when it could log one short message. Awful. Eyewateringly awful.

Comment: In addition, `Collectors.toSet()`  returns an un-ordered `Set`. Try a `List` if you want to keep the ordering produced by `sorted`.

Comment: Or `Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)`.

Comment: Putting the words "set" and "ordered" into the same sentence is like asking for ice-fire.

Comment: Oh, and this `.map(it -> { it.setVersion(null); return it; })` is a travestly - mutating the underlying object in a `map` method breaks all sorts of contracts. To be honest - I think you need to read a lot more about Java before writing any more code.

Comment: I suppose it's more of a request for a [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) to be fair @Mörre

Answer (score 3):

Well, you are sorting them, then add the elements to a `HashSet` which breaks the sorted order. Collect those to  `LinkedHashSet` instead, like `collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new))`

Btw why not simply `Cmparator.naturalOrder()` since your dates look like they are already `Comparable`. Or `Comparator.comparing(x -> x.getCreatedDate().toLocalDateTime())`

Comment: Also the comparator is invalid.

Comment: "_why not simply `Comparator.naturalOrder()`_" - becuase they are a nested property of `Announcement`. `Comparator.comparing(a -> a.getCreatedDate().toLocalDateTime())` would be the idiomatic approach.

Comment: @BoristheSpider right, typing on the phone is not the ultimate pleasure when answering SO. Thank u

Comment: @BoristheSpider oh god yes! :)

Comment: @Eugene worst scenario is when you finish typing and then post the answer then you immediately see someone has posted the exact same answer 1-2 mins ago :-|